# How do I format the input file to line up as rows instead of columns using my variables and with unique identifiers (using the awk command)?

Tags: bash, awk, format

I am attempting to sort the input of a file into rows instead of columns. For example, if my input is (excluding the blank spaces between each line):

> ID0001 G0001
>
> ID0001 G0004
>
> ID0001 G2332
>
> ID0001 G2332
>
> ID0002 G0002
>
> ID0002 G2332

- The output should contain no duplicates in the same ID, but it is okay to have a duplicate number in a different ID. (Again, excluding the blank spaces between each line.)

Output:

> ID0001 G00001, G00004, G2332
>
> ID0002 G0002, G2332

This is what I currently have:

```
#!/bin/bash

uniq $1 > edited.original_ID.txt

counter=1
echo "$(awk 'NR==1{print $1}' edited.original_ID.txt) " >> out.csv

cat edited.original_ID.txt | while read line
do
  UNIQUE_ID=$(awk '{print $1}' "NR==$counter" edited.original_ID.txt)
  NEXT_ID=$(awk '{print $1}' "NR==$((counter+1))" edited.original_ID.txt)

  if [ "${UNIQUE_ID}" == "${NEXT_ID}" ]
  then
     awk "NR==$counter" | awk '{print $2}' edited.original_ID.txt | xargs >> out.csv
  elif [ "${UNIQUE_ID}" != "${NEXT_ID}" ]
  then
     echo "$(awk "NR==$counter" | awk '{print $1}' edited.original_ID.txt)" >> out.csv
     echo -n "$(awk "NR==$counter" | awk '{print $1}' edited.original_ID.txt) " >> out.csv
  fi

  ((counter++))
done
```

As of now, my code does not end unless I forcefully terminate it. I am quite positive that my error is in the awk commands, but I am unsure how to manipulate it so that it will take in my variable and the first part of the column. If anyone can help with my error, I would greatly appreciate it! *I should note that you will see that I have written awk in different ways, I was attempting to see which ones would work/are okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`

```
awk -v OFS=, '!tmp[$1,$2]++{arr[$1] =($1 in arr ? arr[$1] OFS : "" ) $2}
              END{for(i in arr)print i" "arr[i]}' infile
```

**Explanation:**

```
awk -v OFS=, '# call awk, set output field separator as comma              

              #  tmp is array, and field1 and field2 being array key/index
              # !tmp[$1,$2]++ takes care of non duplicate values
              # ++ is post increment, so whenever awk sees repetition of index, it will be incremented 
              # but since we are interested to avoid duplicates, 
              # so we take it only once 

              !tmp[$1,$2]++{ 

                  # arr is array, field1 being array key/index
                  # $1 in arr : if array has key before,
                  # then previous array value will be concatenated with 2nd field value, else just second field value

                  arr[$1] =($1 in arr ? arr[$1] OFS : "" ) $2
              }

              # end block which will be executed at then end as name says
              END{

                  # iterate array arr, 
                  # and print array key, and array value

                  for(i in arr)
                     print i" "arr[i]
              }
              ' infile
```

**Test Results:**

```
$ cat infile
ID0001 G0001
ID0001 G0004
ID0001 G2332
ID0001 G2332
ID0002 G0002
ID0002 G2332

$ awk -v OFS=, '!tmp[$1,$2]++{arr[$1] =($1 in arr ? arr[$1] OFS : "" ) $2}END{for(i in arr)print i" "arr[i]}' infile
ID0001 G0001,G0004,G2332
ID0002 G0002,G2332
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

A small script 'idsort.sh' as a Bash solution:

```
    #!/bin/bash -

    declare -A ID

    while read id gval ; do
      ID[$id]+=$gval"\n"
    done < "$1"

    for id in ${!ID[@]}; do
      echo $id $( printf  ${ID[$id]} | sort --unique )
    done | sort
```

Call it like this:

```
   idsort.sh infile > outfile
```

The first loop gathers all G-values for a given ID as a string with \n as separator.
The second loop pipes these values to a sort command and outputs the unique G-values after the associated ID. These line are sorted  by ascending IDs by the final sort after the second loop.